# How I can preserve shapes When modify a workbook openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file with formating an shapes, but when  I modify it whit openpyxl, the shapes disappear, can I maintain the shapes, or need to redo the shapes(lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) all charts, images, etc. will be lost when working with an existing file.

Comment: Updated [documentation link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) P.S. I can't modify the answer because I get "Suggested edit queue is full" message

Comment: Thanks for the note. The statement is no longer entirely true in that charts and images can now generally be read and support for shapes is coming.

Comment: @CharlieClark any idea what the status is on the shapes?