# Jupyter Notebook is removing shapes from my Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

I successfully managed to upload an Excel (.xlsx) file to my Jupyter Notebook. This is what the Excel sheet looks like:[image]

With my code, I managed to write a value in the cell below "Flow entering DGS1" (cell K13) with the following code:

```
import openpyxl

#the name of my workbook
wbkName = 'DGS Tool interface.xlsx'
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(wbkName)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

#I want to write into the cell at row 13 and column 11
Leakage_cell=sheet_obj.cell(row=13,column=11)

#The value written in this cell is obtained with a function I built called "Leakage"
Leakage_cell.value=Leakage(1000,200)

#Save the changes so that the newly written value appears in my workbook
wb_obj.save(filename = 'DGS Tool interface.xlsx')
```

Now, when I redownload my notebook after running the code, the value is succesfully written in the cell, but all of arrows and "non-cell" elements are deleted as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get Jupyter to keep all images of an Excel sheet? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351066/how-i-can-preserve-shapes-when-modify-a-workbook-openpyxl

Comment: The link it leads to doesn't exist anymore

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html. Side note, Jupyter notebook isn't the issue, it's openpyxl.

Comment: "openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name". So if I save the file with a different name, then it should work?

Comment: No, because "openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file."